# Custom Authorization Filter getting duplicate identities on ReExecute

Tags: c#, asp.net, authorization, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I am using a custom authorization filter within dotnet core, however I have noticed a peculiarity.

The `OnAuthorization` method has a context that holds the Identities of the logged-in user which in my use case should be one. This works fine throughout my app, however I then configured error pages using `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute(...);` or `app.UseExceptionHandler(...);` and whenever these are triggered, i.e. if an error occurs then within the `OnAuthorization` the context has a duplicate identity.

I am unsure if this is a bug within dotnet core or there is some setup that I have not quite configured correctly. The second identity that is added appears to be a duplicate of the one I am expecting.

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    // identifies users on POP Forums actions
    options.Filters.Add(typeof(MyAttribute));
});
```

MyAttribute.cs:

```
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
{
    var claimsCount = context.HttpContext.User.Identities.Count();
    if (claimsCount > 1)
    {
        var oops = "Something went wrong";
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1316) open on the aspnet/Security GitHub site about this bug. The problem occurs because the Error Handling Middleware replays the request on top of the same HttpContext, and merges the identities.

ASP.NET Core 2.0 should resolve this issue since it uses a single Authentication middleware.

A possible workaround in the meantime would be to just get the first Identity:

```
User.Identities.FirstOrDefault();
```